# Launching terminated app by background notification

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Is it possible to launch a terminated app by a silent/background notification and keep it active past the 30s time limit?

I've been testing this for a while, but seems like no matter what is being done, app gets terminated once the 30sec time limit is reached or fetch handler returns a result. Starting a background location update doesn't prevent app from being terminated. Location updates are being generated.

Is there a way to keep app running indefinitely? Apple documentation doesn't mention anything about what can/cannot be done. Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use significant location change to get background location updates or you can start a background location update session before your app enters the background (blue bar will show) or have always location permission and start updates before moving to the background.  What, exactly are you trying to achieve. You can't keep an app running indefinitely in the background but you can get frequent execution opportunities if you are using background location.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of these capabilities and they are being used. The problem I have is when app gets terminated by the user. If user doesn't move enough, significant location update doesn't trigger an event and app is not launched. I'm looking for a way to launch an app from a terminated state(on demand) and keep it running for at least 1 hour. If it's even possible

Comment: That is not possible. The user terminated the app so it is dead.